# Yii2 ActiveRecord link/unlink with more than one model

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii2, relational-database

In my Yii2 app, I have the models `User`, `Group` and `Role` with the following relationship: users are members of groups and have roles in these group, and/or global roles.

I use one join table, `User_Role` with the columns `UserId`, `RoleId` and `GroupId` to store the information on the links between the model. If `GroupId` is `NULL`, the role is global, otherwise it contains the id of the group in which the user has this role.

As far as I understand, Yii2's `BaseActiveRecord::link/unlink` mechanism is not really meant to (un)link more than two models. Linking works ok, because `BaseActiveRecord::link` takes an optional `extraColumns` parameter in which I can pass  `['GroupId'=> ... ]`. However, there is no such parameter in `BaseActiveRecord::unlink`, so I have to resort to a workaround:

```
 // class User
 // ...
 /**
   * Internal. Populated temporarily during relational queries.
   * @var int|null
   */
  public $groupId = null;

  /**
   * @return ActiveQuery
   */         
  public function getUserRoles()
  {
    $link = ['UserId' => 'id'];
    if( $this->groupId) $link['GroupId'] = "groupId";
    return $this->hasMany(User_Role::class, $link );
  } 

  /**
   * Returns the roles of the user, depending on the groupId property.
   * @return ActiveQuery
   */
  public function getRoles()
  {
    return $this
      ->hasMany( Role::class, ['id' => 'RoleId'] )
      ->via('userRoles', function(ActiveQuery $query){
        return $query->andWhere(['GroupId' => $this->groupId]);
      });
  }
```

And set the `groupId` property before unlinking or doing other kind of queries.

Of course, I could do the unlinking part "by hand" and not rely on the `unlink` method. But maybe there are smarter ways of multi-model linkages that would not require custom-crafted queries. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you linking with GroupId parameter in extraColumns? What is your scenario to link and unlink models?

Comment: The `GroupId` column value determines in which group the user has the given role, so there is always a link between a `User`, a `Role` and a `Group` model instance (except when `GroupId` is `NULL`). So the scenario of link and unlink is: when the administrator assigns or removes roles to/from users in the admininstration panel, it is always in the context of a group (including a "global" group). Does that make it clearer?

Comment: i think better solution to use deleteAll() with conditions

Comment: You are right. I should probably just do UserRoles::deleteAll([userId=>xx,groupId=>yy,roleId=>zz]). Much easier. Thank you.